# Where do I put React component initialization code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to learning React.js, I'm working on progress bar with animation and I found this code that I want to implement into my code but i don't know where to place the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/1/

I don't know where to put this JavaScript code:

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
 width: "70%"
}, 3000);
```

.

Here's my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var Alert = require('react-bootstrap').Alert;
var VisualResults = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div className="columns medium-12 large-12 small-centered" id="mainStyle">
        <div style={{marginTop: 30}}>
          <div className="progress">
            <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
                role="progress-bar" style={{"width" : "0%"}}>

                {$(".progress-bar").animate({
                    width: "70%"
                }, 3000)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = VisualResults;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle event. This will get called right after the component is mounted to the DOM. Meaning that you can get it by class and animate it.

```
var React = require('react');
var Alert = require('react-bootstrap').Alert;
var VisualResults = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        $(".progress-bar").animate({width: "70%"}, 3000)
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="columns medium-12 large-12 small-centered"
                 id="mainStyle">
                <div style={{marginTop: 30}}>
                    <div className="progress">
                        <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
                             role="progress-bar" style={{"width" : "0%"}}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
module.exports = VisualResults;
```

Comment: Ohh I did not know about the componentDidMount. Thank you for your help!